# arrayformula causes "coordinates of the target range are outside the dimensions of the sheet array formula" error

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, array-formulas

I copy the data of **Sheet1** to **Sheet2** with the code below.

When I inserted an `arrayformula(A2:A&B2:B)` in **Sheet2**, the sript stopped working and i got the error:

> coordinates of the target range are outside the dimensions of the
> sheet array formula

When I deleted the arrayformula, the execution of the script completed successfully.

What should i change to the code (or to the arrayformula) to get them to cooperate?

```
function dailyLog() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var logSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  var lastRow = logSheet.getLastRow();
  var range = sourceSheet.getDataRange();
  range.copyTo(logSheet.getRange(lastRow + 2, 1), {contentsOnly: true}); // paste under previous paste
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### **Issue:**

The input range and the output range do not match:

**Input range:** `range = sourceSheet.getDataRange()`

**Output range:** `logSheet.getRange(lastRow + 2, 1)`

The output range is a single cell, while the input range is the full data range (therefore multiple cells).

### Solution:

If the input range is dynamic it is a better idea to use `getValues/setValues` instead:

```
function dailyLog() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var logSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  var lastRow = logSheet.getLastRow();
  var values = sourceSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  logSheet.getRange(lastRow+1,1,values.length,values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

and now the size of the data (`values`) is dynamically set with the help of the `length` function.

### Reference:

- [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues())
- [setValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_range#setValues)

Comment: thank you. the error message disappeared but no data were pasted in Sheet2. fyi i'm trying to copy the range Sheet1!A1:Z1000 (or the whole Sheet1) to Sheet2.

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet? remove the sensitive information @thanasix Also check if the data is pasted all the way to the bottom of `Sheet2`. If that is the case, then remove every data in `Sheet2` to make sure `lastRow+1` equals to `1` in the beginning of the process.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10PlEM8ZlAD0mK_a1J_LMGTatB2t2dVJguynWddVoVzk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @thanasix just delete the current `Sheet2` and create a new `Sheet2` and start fresh and it will work. Not sure if it is a bug or not, but `getLastRow` returns 29999 but I don't see any data there so I am not sure why is that hapenning. But you can create a new sheet and get rid of this bug.

Comment: @thanasix I think the issue is you have somewhere in `Sheet2` an array formula that expands until the bottom of the sheet and this is why the script pastes the data to the very bottom of the sheet. So to be 100% sure that is working, start **fresh**. Delete the sheet and create a new one and the script will work perfectly fine.